# KeyInput won't work while running a while (JCreator,Applet)

Tags: java, awt, paint, keylistener, jcreator

Supposedly whenever you press a key, it should access the code, but it doesn't and neither do I or my teacher know why. Here's the code:

```
class KeyInput implements KeyListener{
Actor player;
Graphics gBuffer;

public KeyInput(Actor player, Graphics gBuffer){
    JTextField typingArea = new JTextField(20);
    typingArea.addKeyListener(this);
    this.player = player;
    this.gBuffer = gBuffer;
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        player.modActor(1);
        gBuffer.drawString("ENTER",150,100);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        player.modActor(2);
        gBuffer.drawString("ENTER",150,100);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        player.modActor(3);
        gBuffer.drawString("ENTER",150,100);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        player.modActor(4);
        gBuffer.drawString("ENTER",150,100);
    }
}
```

}

And this is the while that plays during the program:

```
   public void paint(Graphics g){ //main method to be called to play(g);
    do{
        drawBackground(gBuffer);
        gBuffer.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,20));
        gBuffer.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        gBuffer.drawString("Score: " + (int)score,18,20);
        gBuffer.drawString("Score: " + (int)score,22,20);
        gBuffer.drawString("Score: " + (int)score,20,22);
        gBuffer.drawString("Score: " + (int)score,20,18);
        gBuffer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        gBuffer.drawString("Score: " + (int)score,20,20);
        play(gBuffer);
        g.drawImage(virtualMem,0,0,this);
        if(lose==false){
            gBuffer.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,50));
            gBuffer.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            gBuffer.drawString("GAME OVER",42,200);
            gBuffer.drawString("GAME OVER",38,200);
            gBuffer.drawString("GAME OVER",40,202);
            gBuffer.drawString("GAME OVER",40,198);
            gBuffer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            gBuffer.drawString("GAME OVER",40,200);
            gBuffer.drawString("Final Score: " + (int)score,20,260);
        }
    }while(lose);

}
```

The key inputs need to move an actor I have, but it doesn't move at all, and yes, I click inside the applets every time. Any idea of whats going on?

EDIT: I have now gave up on keyListener and tried keyBindings, but I'm new with them and probably have something wrong, please help me...

```
public void init() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    this.setSize(400,700);
    this.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    player = new Actor(180,500);
    virtualMem = createImage(400,800);
    gBuffer = virtualMem.getGraphics();

    panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "up");
    panel.getActionMap().put("up", new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         gBuffer.drawString("IT WORKS", 150, 150);
         repaint();
        }
    });

    panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "down");
    panel.getActionMap().put("down", new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         gBuffer.drawString("IT WORKS", 150, 150);
         repaint();
        }
    });

    panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "left");
    panel.getActionMap().put("left", new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         gBuffer.drawString("IT WORKS", 150, 150);
         repaint();
        }
    });

    panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "right");
    panel.getActionMap().put("right", new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         gBuffer.drawString("IT WORKS", 150, 150);
         repaint();
        }
    });

}
```

The while is still the same (play). When ever I click something it doesn't access the methods either.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  But stick with the key bindings..

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that maybe that infinite loop inside `paint`() is interfering with the events management (remember that there is a single thread for those 2 things to be done).  Why don't you just fire a `repaint`() on every significant event (for example, a key press)?

Comment: Tried it but still doesn't work. What I noticed it's that it doesn't even access the KeyPressed method, since I tried to just output something straight in when it's called but still won't work. I also tried to put only the method inside the game class but won't work either. Here's a small picture of the game, in case it helps. http://puu.sh/92pQ2/9c34196c4a.png What is supposed to move is the blue thingie at the center- down